# Java SWT in Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. Why I can't compile any prototype that I create?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, swt

I was installed the swt plugins correctly but when I try to run de program, it marks an error and I can't solve it.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uxe8.png)

The edition of the Java is for Java Developers.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkM7t.png)

To run the GUI in SWT mode, not Swing mode. I use the correct plugin when I try to run it, I can't find any solution.

Comment: Is SWT on your classpath? According to the screenshot it compiles fine, but you get an error when running. Please show the command line used to run it: in the run configuration (_Run > Run Configurations..._) there is a button _Show Command Line_ for that. By the way, it looks like you have opened a workspace with the _Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_ that was created with _Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers_ (therefore some views and the _Java EE_ is missing).

Comment: Copy and paste error messages to your question (formatted as a coffee block). Text is searchable, but screenshots are not.